# Add number to Wordpress post

Tags: wordpress

i need to add counter next to wordpress title in my wordpress homepage.
1st post have "1" second have "2" etc. You can check my idea in design(image attatched). Thanks for help.
[image]

Comment: Show your used code.

Comment: Image its not code. Its just design  how i will like to be. With default post type in wordpress

Comment: Add an iterator counter to your code in the query loop.

Comment: can you be more specific with that? @disinfor

Comment: @Vachos Add your code and I can be more specific. Stack Overflow questions need to show what you've tried, not just an image. It's nice that you want what you've designed, but what have you tried - in code - to do it?

Answer (score 0):

So its be simple us that with some css:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: section;                     /* Set a counter named 'section', and it`s initial value is 0. */
}

h3::before {
  counter-increment: section;                 /* Increment the value of section counter by 1 */
  content: counter(section);                  /* Display the value of section counter */
}
```

found in: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters